# Any news of Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: updates

The current version of Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi 3B is not compatible with the 3B+ version. I've tried. I would like to know when there might be an update.

Answer (score 1):

We’re planning on releasing Ubuntu MATE images for the Raspberry Pi around the time 18.04.1 is released, which should be sometime in July 2018. It takes about a month to get the Raspberry Pi images built and tested and we simply don’t have time to do this in time for the April release of 18.04.